# iOS HTML Input Tag Stops Scrolling in Scrollable Element

Tags: ios, html, css, webkit, mobile-website

My mobile website has a fixed scrollable (`overflow-y:auto`) element that contains `input` tags. On iPhone and iPad, touching and moving on the `input` tags block the element from scrolling but touching and moving on labels (or anything else) do not. This issue does not occur on Android.

The `input` tags used to be part of a `table` before I switched to `div`s for layout and the scrolling worked then for iOS and Android. Is there a reason why scrolling is blocked when the `input` tags are not in `table`s? I really prefer not having to go back to `table`s for layout.

I also tried `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and it fixed the issue for iPhone but prevents scrolling completely on iPad on top of allowing users to scroll horizontally which I don't want.

**UPDATE:** If the soft keyboard is active everything works as intended. Only when the keyboard is not active when I get the issue.

Comment: Stupid question, but by "touching the input tags" you do mean giving focus to the controls on the resuting page, right? Not when editing?

Comment: Yes I think... What I mean is that I should be able to scroll when I touch the input tags and move without bringing up the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the browser. Do you use safari or another browser? Maybe updating the browser or trying it on a different iOS device will work?