# Issues with touch scroll on iOS when focusing inputs

Tags: html, ios, input, scroll

I am having some issues with a scrollable div on iOS. When trying to scroll by touching outside an input, it scrolls ok without any problem but when I try to scroll and I touch an input to start scrolling (there are a lot of chances that it happens because it is a div with a lot of inputs) it scrolls the whole window instead scrolling the div. I don't have that problem either in desktop or Android. I found a similar question ([iOS HTML Input Tag Stops Scrolling in Scrollable Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333410/ios-html-input-tag-stops-scrolling-in-scrollable-element)) but it doesn't have any answer either. While I don't find any good solution, I decided to prevent the event `touchmove` when the user touches an input, but it is not exactly what I want.

Maybe someone already faced this problem and can help. I would really appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784118/scrolling-on-ios-device-finger-input-tag/28862015#28862015  .  I have provided details there or what was causing my issue.  Can you see if it is the same for you?

Comment: Please acept answer if it's correct for you

Answer (score 43):

To get native momentum scrolling on iOS 5+, you'll need:

```
div {
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Source: [Overflow](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

Maybe you also need:

```
div > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

Source: [Similar question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122689/1827690)

Source 2: [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9801687/1827690)

Comment: This has nothing to do with what OP was asking. Problem is that if you initiate drag-scroll from an input such as a textbox (which triggers touchmove event), the entire document scrolls instead of the inner scrollable area.

Comment: this works but instead of putting it in div. Put it in the html or body.

`html { overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}`

Comment: god damn IOS - should have found this earlier!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is the correct way to "fix" this problem without adversely impacting the usability of a page.

Answer (score 7):

This stuff made me crazy too, after testing everything, I found the following answer from Thomas Bachem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798681/2981586) working and made it simpler in jquery.

Just add a class `scrollFix` to the inputs and you are ready to go. (or directly apply that js to any inputs/textarea using`$('input, textarea')`

Now when you touch and scroll on an input on iOS 8+, the input get all its "pointer-events" disabled (including the problematic behavior). Those "pointer-events" are enabled when we detect a simple touch.

```
$('.scrollFix').css("pointer-events","none");

$('body').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    $('.scrollFix').css("pointer-events","auto");
});
$('body').on('touchmove', function(e) {
    $('.scrollFix').css("pointer-events","none");
});
$('body').on('touchend', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.scrollFix').css("pointer-events", "none");
    },0);
});
```

Comment: Been hunting for hours for a fix for the Iphone IOS9 and this worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: Tried using this with Ionic (hybrid web wrapper).  It's a bit wonky when it comes to ionic.  if I tap into an input, It scrolls the page to the right spot and opens the keyboard, but it doesn't actually focus on the input.  Good start here for me at least.

Comment: this works for scrolling, but makes the form fields not selectable/ so you cant fill out the form.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky workaround, but by doing this I was able to make scrolling work even on form inputs. The JS forces a reflow in the rendering engine, which is where the bug in iOS8 Safari lies. Changing the height to auto also improved scrolling when *focused* on a form element, since scrolling is forcibly handled by the browser when focused.

Markup:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop-container">
  <div class="modal-backdrop">
    <div class="modal> <!-- Content --> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop-container {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
// reflow when changing input focus
        $modalInputs = $('.modal').find(':input');
        modalInputs.on('focus', function() {
            var offsetHeight = modal.$backdrop[0].offsetHeight;
            modal.$backdropContainer.css({
                'height': 'auto'
            });
        });
        modalInputs.on('blur', function() {
            var offsetHeight = modal.$backdrop[0].offsetHeight;
            modal.$backdropContainer.css({
                'height': ''
            });
        });
```

Not sure of the `var offsetHeight = modal.$backdrop[0].offsetHeight;` line is needed, since both this and changing the height value should force a reflow.